# Checking domain availibility with DNS

Tags: c#, dns

I was implementing DNS getbyhostname by address but The software fails if a user has custom DNS addresses like OpenDNS in the network or is inside a private network (Office or School or Behind a firewall).

Basicly i am checking domain avilibility
Any solutions

My code so far

```
IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostByName(adderess);
MessageBox.Show(hostInfo.HostName);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use whois to check if a domain name has been registered or not.

Besides it being the purpose of whois, it's also possible that a domain name may not have any DNS records, but still be registered.

Comment: Maybe point the OP to code such as this...http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/christianhanssom/WhoIsCMH12022005000458AM/WhoIsCMH.aspx which performs a whois query within c#

Comment: Try this link, there is class file in C# to search for domain name http://coderbuddy.wordpress.com/2010/10/13/domain-name-search-in-c/